# How do I rename my Xcode project without losing my data?

Tags: ios, xcode

How do I rename my Xcode project (aka .xcodeproj) without losing my data? It gives me an error like this before breaking my whole project:

> The file for the container that was at
>   *appName*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace has disappeared. Do you want to re-save the container or close it?

I am using Xcode 6.3.1

Comment: I am on 6.3.1 now. What should I do now?

Comment: it keeps giving me that error

Comment: I've been trying to rename it since 6.0

Comment: Apple says for my scholarship application for WWDC, I need to make my app my full name. I already named the app my name but my .xcodeproj and all that needs to be my name as well.

Comment: Won't they think  that it's not mine? Should I leave them a note?

Comment: well thanks for your help! I'll just let them know that it wouldn't let me rename the .xcodeproj without it breaking, should I do that??

Comment: oh but how do i move everything? it's an actual file appName.xcodeproj that I want to rename

Answer (score 0):

What name？
Project Name？Project Folder Name？or App Display Name？

“Do you want to re-save the container or close it?”

I think you rename your project folder name.
You can reopen your project in finder.

Comment: it's the actual file to open in Xcode. appName.xcodeproj - where I want to change "appName"